# nginx reverse proxy enforce https for LetsEncrypt SSL

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy, lets-encrypt

I have remote Linux Ubuntu 20 running Nginx reverse proxy for a Node app with LetsEncrypt SSL cert recently installed and I want to enforce https on all requests. Currently both http and https work as expected. How can I update my config to redirect all http to https?

Protocol: IPV4

Firewall: `Nginx Full ALLOW Anywhere`

Node app location `/var/www/html/mydomain`

Nginx config location: `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

Nginx config:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html/mydomain;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;

        location ^~ /assets/ {
                gzip_static on;
                expires 12h;
                add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

        location / {
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/gfrweb.site/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
```

The site is working for both http and https and I want it to redirect all http traffic to https.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move your http listener into a single server block and use this:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

And remove the lines

```
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
```

from your other server block.

https://linuxize.com/post/redirect-http-to-https-in-nginx/

Comment: Thanks Geilmaker! Yes that worked, just to be clear for people seeing the answer you need to create 2 seperate server blocks `server {}`: one with redirect and the other containing all the rest of the config above without the 2 `listen` lines